# Цикличный вывод значений массива из Jquery в div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть проблема! Как из массива значений вывести каждое значение в отдельный `div`, при этом при повторе цикла, запись делать в новый `div` с тем же классом?

Сейчас вывод выглядит так:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

А нужно так:

```
<div class="place">1</div>
<div class="place">2</div>
<div class="place">3</div>
```

$.each(data,function(index,value) {
var place = value.place;
var table_number= value.table_number;
$("<div></div>").text(table_number).appendTo(".table_number");
$("<div></div>").text(place).appendTo(".place"); 

   <div class="table_number"></div>
   <div class="place"></div>

Comment: Так и не понятно, какие входные данные? Добавить `place` в качестве класса, еще?

Comment: Да, именно так добавить place в качестве класса

Comment: Во все `div` на странице? Селектор у этих дивов есть, как к ним обратиться?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(d => {d.classList.add('place')})` Если на все, то так можно.

Answer (score -2):

Код ниже, и класс `place` можно перенести [в переменную](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```js
const array = [0, 1, 'two', 3, 4];

for(let one of array){
    $('.table_number').append(`<div class="place">${one}</div>`);
}
```

each и\или forEach - прошлый век, кстати. И от них нужно отказываться

Comment: Почему прошлый век?

Comment: @NeedHate не могут в async

Comment: А что для всех циклов требуется всегда асинхронность? Вы сами написали синхронный код выше, получается for - это прошлый век по вашей логике.